# Most Efficient Way to Process Subquery For First Record

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of customer ID's and a table of customer data.  A customer can change ID's, but I want to query their earliest date in some cases, and the latest date in others.  For example, I have two tables:

```
tbl_a
id        active_id
a         aa
b         aa
c         aa
d         bb
e         bb

tbl_b
id         date      city
a        1/1/2012    Dallas
b        1/1/2013    Houston
c        2/1/2013    Austin
d        1/1/2003    San Antonio
e        3/3/2013    El Paso

tbl_c
id    value
a      50
b      50
b      50
c      50
d      10
e      10
e      10
```

How would I query the data to return a single active_id with the EARLIEST date and MOST RECENT city while summing the data from tbl_c?  For example, return the following:

```
active_id    date      city     sum(value)
aa           1/1/2012  Austin   200 
bb           1/1/2003  El Paso  30
```

In semantic terms, I'm trying to find the first date and most recent city for any active_id, while summing the transaction values.

Comment: what version of SQL server do you using?

Comment: It's most similar to standard SQL server.  It's a teradata query, but that's not important for this particular application I don't think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use windowed functions (and don't have access to `first_value` function):

```
with cte as (
    select
        row_number() over(partition by a.active_id order by b.date asc) as rn1,
        row_number() over(partition by a.active_id order by b.date desc) as rn2,
        a.active_id, b.date, b.city
    from tbl_a as a
        inner join tbl_b as b on b.id = a.id
)
select
    c.active_id,
    c1.date,
    c2.city
from (select distinct active_id from cte) as c
    left outer join cte as c1 on c1.active_id = c.active_id and c1.rn1 = 1
    left outer join cte as c2 on c2.active_id = c.active_id and c2.rn2 = 1
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/54668/5)</kbd>**

If you can use `first_value` function:

```
with cte as (
    select
        first_value(b.date) over(partition by a.active_id order by b.date asc) as date,
        first_value(b.city) over(partition by a.active_id order by b.date desc) as city,
        a.active_id
    from tbl_a as a
        inner join tbl_b as b on b.id = a.id
)
select distinct
    active_id, date, city
from cte
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
;WITH DATA 
     AS (SELECT T1.ACTIVE_ID, 
                T2.* 
         FROM   TABLEA T1 
                INNER JOIN TABLEB T2 
                        ON T1.ID = T2.ID), 
     DATA2 
     AS (SELECT T1.ACTIVE_ID, 
                SUM(T2.VALUE) TOT_VALUE 
         FROM   TABLEA T1 
                INNER JOIN TABLEC T2 
                        ON T1.ID = T2.ID 
         GROUP  BY ACTIVE_ID) 
SELECT T3.ACTIVE_ID, 
       DATE, 
       CITY, 
       T5.TOT_VALUE AS [SUM(VALUE)] 
FROM   DATA T3 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT MIN(DATE) MAXDATE, 
                          ACTIVE_ID 
                   FROM   DATA 
                   GROUP  BY ACTIVE_ID)T4 
               ON T3.ACTIVE_ID = T4.ACTIVE_ID 
                  AND T3.DATE = T4.MAXDATE 
       INNER JOIN DATA2 T5 
               ON T3.ACTIVE_ID = T5.ACTIVE_ID
```

A working example can be found on <kbd>[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/df351/5)</kbd>.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

This assumes `tbl_a <--> tbl_b` is 1 - 1

`tran_sum` can either be put as `max(tran_sum)` like here, or added to the group by

```
Select
    active_id,
    max(case r1 when 1 then date end) date,
    max(case r2 when 1 then city end) city,
    max(tran_sum)
From (
    Select
        a.active_id,
        sum(c.value) over (partition by a.active_id) tran_sum,
        row_number() over (partition by a.active_id order by date) as r1,
        b.date,
        row_number() over (partition by a.active_id order by date desc) as r2,
        b.city
    From
        tbl_a a
            inner join
        tbl_b b
            on a.id = b.id
            inner join
        tbl_c c
            on a.id = c.id
    ) x
Group By
    active_id;
```